# Installing cyberoam client on Kali Linux(Bash says no file or directory found)

Tags: linux, bash, software-installation, kali-linux

I can see the file when I invoke `ls`, but when I try to access the file, BASH exits with the following error.

```
bash: ./crclient: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `chmod +x crclient`

Comment: Where did the file come from?  Did it have any installation instructions with it?

Comment: that returns nothing.. I got it from here https://kb.cyberoam.com/default.asp?id=372

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking a file that is not executable, or is missing required libs.
How to check if it's executable is fair easy:

```
 [ -x crclient ] && echo "File is executable" || echo "File is not executable"
```

To check required libs:

```
ldd crclient
```

Comment: the file is executable on

[ -x crclient ] && echo "File is executable" || echo "File is not executable"

but ldd crclient returns

not a dynamic executable

Comment: I've downloaded the crcclient you have problem with. If you run "readelf -a crcclient" you'll see that it asks for "/lib/ld-linux.so.2" which probably you are missing. crcclient is an ELF32 bit, so you need libc6-i386 package (if your distribution is debian based and is an x86_64).

Comment: Yes it seems to be ELF32 bit. What do I do now??

Comment: If you have a debian-based distribution, install libc6-i386 with "apt-get install libc6-i386".

Comment: I get this
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libc6-i386

Comment: Please specify what distribution you are using, and post the output of the command "lsb_release -a"

Comment: i believe its a Debian GNU/Linux distribution... 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description: Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release: kali-rolling
Codename: kali-rolling

Comment: kali is not a proper distribution for your purpose. Installing 32-bit packages on 64bit kali may lead you into trouble. Anyway, this is what you can do:                                                                                         dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install ia32-libs

Comment: Still gives me this error E: Unable to locate package ia32-libs

Comment: I think you need to learn how to install/search packages on debian based distributions. Check this doc and come back when you've clear in mind what you are doing: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianPackageManagement

Comment: @FrancescoColista   Thank you for this comment : "crcclient is an ELF32 bit, so you need libc6-i386 package".  My OS is Linux Mint 18.x  64 bit. It lacked 32 bit compatibility for crclient. It did not show up on ldd output either. 
Problem is fixed after running `sudo apt-get install libc6-i386`